# jQuery Syntax Help

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I need some help with jQuery syntax.

I'm trying to modify the opacity effect in the code below to something like fadeIn.

```
jQuery("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with the code you entered is that you're chaining in the wrong place.  Try this:

```
var $featured = $('#featured');
$featured.tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
$featured.tabs( "rotate" , 5000 , true );
```

Comment: This fixes the fx issue in ie... although I'm still having issues with removing or changing the effect

Answer (score 0):

I use the fadein method on the jQuery object to hava a fadin and out effect.

```
$("#featured").fadeIn('slow')
```

Read on:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: My problem is that I'm not familiar with the syntax of how to incorporate this with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to fade the element in and out. I made it as simple as possible to understand. Hope it helps! http://jsfiddle.net/CzT8s/1/

Just hit run to watch how the code renders.